# Google Autocomplete - дублирование запросов

Tags: android, google-autocomplete

В программе использую автозаполнение.
Ниже много кода, но надеюсь кто то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, либо осилит его ;-)

Для экономии количества запросов выполняю запрос к серверу только на второй букве и каждой, кратной 4-й, а так же если последний введеный символ пробел или дефис.

Проблема в том, что в нужные моменты отправляются не один запрос, а два.

Вставил два лога PlaceProvider.java (в самом низу):

```
Log.e("AUTOCOMPLETE", String.valueOf(resultList));
```

и GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter -> getFilter() -> performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)

```
Log.e("AUTOCOMPLETE", "___Last: " + lastSym + " " + String.valueOf(constraint) + constraint.length());
```

Ввожу 4 буквы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат в логе

```
05-24 20:44:16.077 24614-25388/com.khasang.forecast E/AUTOCOMPLETE: ___Last: н Магн4
05-24 20:44:16.077 24614-25388/com.khasang.forecast E/AUTOCOMPLETE: [Малое Козино, Нижегородская область, Россия, Магнитогорск, Челябинская область, Россия, Малаховка, Московская область, Россия, Малоярославец, Калужская область, Россия, Мантурово, Костромская область, Россия]
05-24 20:44:16.845 24614-25388/com.khasang.forecast E/AUTOCOMPLETE: ___Last: н Магн4
05-24 20:44:16.845 24614-25388/com.khasang.forecast E/AUTOCOMPLETE: [Магнитогорск, Челябинская область, Россия, Магнитка, Челябинская область, Россия, Магнитный, Курская область, Россия, Магнитский, Челябинская область, Россия, Магна, Республика Калмыкия, Россия]
```

Судя по логу получается, что запрос посылается два раза, причем результат выполнения запросов отличается. 
С чем это может быть связано?

Код приложения:

Активити:

```
    final GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter googlePlacesAutocompleteAdapter = new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.autocomplete_city_textview_item);
    chooseCity = (DelayedAutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextCityName);
    chooseCity.setAdapter(googlePlacesAutocompleteAdapter);
```

PlacePprovider.java

```
public class PlaceProvider {
    private final static String TAG = PlaceProvider.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static String PLACE_API_BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json";
    private final static String API_KEY = MyApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.place_provider_key);


ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

public ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    try {
        String URL = PLACE_API_BASE_URL + "?key="
                + API_KEY + "&input="
                + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8")
                + "&types=(cities)";
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Request to Google Place API failure");
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                String jsonData = response.body().string();
                Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("predictions");
                    resultList = new ArrayList<String>(jsonArray.length());
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                        resultList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    Log.e("AUTOCOMPLETE", String.valueOf(resultList));
    return resultList;
}
}
```

Адаптер

```
public class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
        implements Filterable {
    private List<String> resultList;
    private PlaceProvider mPlaceProvider;
    private final static int MAX_RESULT = 10;
    private Context mContext;


    public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mContext = context;
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mPlaceProvider = new PlaceProvider();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return resultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_city_textview_item, parent, false);
        }
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_list_item);
        description.setText(getItem(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                if (constraint != null) {
                    char lastSym = constraint.charAt(constraint.length() - 1);
                    if ((constraint.length() % 4 == 0) || (lastSym == ' ') || (lastSym == '-') || (constraint.length() == 2)) {
                        List<String> predictions = mPlaceProvider.autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                        filterResults.values = predictions;
                        filterResults.count = predictions.size();
                    }
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    resultList = (List<String>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался: код был другого разработчика - это огрехи старого кода